# Composer require failed on SSL issue

Tags: symfony, ssl, openssl, composer-php, tls1.2

this is not the first time that I have some problems with openssl but this time I'm really stuck and I do not found any informations about that happened.

When I use the following command, composer thrown an exception

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle
```

[image: Composer exception]

I use composer within a Symfony project.
If anyone know something about this error, he will be welcome !

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

From https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http

*Defaults to true. If set to true only HTTPS URLs are allowed to be downloaded via Composer. I**f you really absolutely need HTTP access to something then you can disable it, but using Let's Encrypt to get a free SSL certificate is generally a better alternative.***

After set the **secure-http** to **false** composer will download unaccessible dependencies over https with http. 
Please be carefull of the text part in bold it's potentially dangerous to set this option to false